# Creating a character array using a loop in C++

Tags: c++, loops

I'm trying to create a C++ Tic-Tac-Toe game, however when I modify the character array (the board itself), it creates two character on the row it was placed on and then on the first element of the next row. The code below is what gathers user input and places it into the board.

```
void changeBoard(int position)
{
int row = position / 3;
int column = position - (row*3);
if((player == 1 & run == 1) || (player == 0 && run == 0))
    Board[row][column] = 'X';
else
    Board[row][column] = 'O';
}

void displayBoard()
{
int i;
int z;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    cout << "\n\n";
    for(z=0;z<3;z++)
    {
        cout << "||" << "  " << Board[i][z] << "  ";
        if(z == 2)
            cout << "||";
    }
}
cout << "\n";
}
```

I have omitted the rest of the code.
The output however when the user inputs position 3 (the last element of the first row), it creates a sign there AND a sign on the first element of the next row.

Any help or explanation of why it is doing this?

Comment: "if((player == 1 & run == 1) || (player == 0 && run == 0))" - maybe that first '&' should be '&&' ..... ?

Comment: @roger_rowland Part of me thinks it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @David - part of me thinks the OP should change it and try it again, that's quicker than thinking about it ;-)

Comment: ... actually, that's that same as "if (player == run)" isn't it?

Comment: I was in Java mode but they both work don't they?

Comment: @roger_rowland The difference between & and && in a boolean expression is that if the expression has already been found to be false '&' will continue checking the expression. This is used when all checks in an expression need to be completed (usually because the checks also mutate some data). && will stop the expression early  if it has already been proven false. The only difference in this case is that 'if((player == 1 & run == 1)' will check both the player and run values, whereas 'player == 0 && run == 0' will check player, and if it is false, not bother checking run. So not a problem here

Comment: What type is Board please? Is it char Board[3][3]?

Comment: The elements of the board go to [2][2]

Answer (score 0):

Use `modulo` (`%`) to find the column, and make sure to minus 1 from positon if you want `3` to be the top right corner of the board.

## Javascript example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/nPMvz/

```
void changeBoard(int position)
{
position--;
int row = position / 3;
int column = position % 3;
if((player == 1 & run == 1) || (player == 0 && run == 0))
    Board[row][column] = 'X';
else
    Board[row][column] = 'O';
}

void displayBoard()
{
int i;
int z;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    cout << "\n\n";
    for(z=0;z<3;z++)
    {
        cout << "||" << "  " << Board[i][z] << "  ";
        if(z == 2)
            cout << "||";
    }
}
cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Could I send you my code so you can see exactly what is wrong with it? As I said at the top, putting in position 3 will create an X in two places for some reason.

Comment: I figured it out, the board had to be [3][3]. I still don't understand why that fixes it though, since [2][2] is a 3x3 matrix